# Downloaded Python but it is Not Working on VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I installed Python 3.10 but am getting the error that Python is not installed (see image below) when I try to run Python in VS Code. I also downloaded the current curated set of SSL root certificates ('certifi') as recommended on the Python installation.

What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[Python is not installed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AefK9.png)

Comment: What OS are you on?

Answer (score 1):

Bro when you download python 3.10 make sure that you tick the add to path option when downloading.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things to do while installing:

- Ensure that both the Install launcher for all users (recommended) and the Add Python 3.9 to PATH checkboxes at the bottom are checked: Usally only first is checked by default.

[image: Python setup]
(*Check **Add python** also*)

- Click on **Install Now** button.
- If not followed the above steps, Completely uninstall and reinstall the python.
- Also see [Python installation guide](https://realpython.com/installing-python/) and [Uninstalling python guide.](https://www.wikihow.com/Uninstall-Python)